# How do I find the error in this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{3m}{(4^m)(3m+5)}
$$

$\frac{4m}{4^m (3m+5)}$ estimates the error in utilizing the sum $s9$ in comparison with the series $\frac{1}{4^m}$.

I found the integral of $\frac{1}{4^m}$ which is $\frac{4^{-m} }{\ln(4)}$

Then, I found the limit of the integral from $9$ to $\infty$ which I got to be $2.8 \cdot 10^{-6}$ so I said $R9 \leq 2.8 \cdot 10^{-6}$

But I can't help but think I got it wrong somehow. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{3m}{(4^m)(3m+5)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^m}-5\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4^m)(3m+5)}=\frac13-5\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4^m)(3m+5)}.
$$

Now, consider the function
$$
f(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{4^m}x^{3m+4}=\frac{x^7}4\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^3}4\right)^m=\frac{x^7}{4-x^3}.
$$

Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4^m)(3m+5)}&=\int_0^1\frac{x^7}{4-x^3}dx\\
&=\int_0^1\left(-x^4-4x-\frac{16x}{x^3-4}\right)dx\\
&=-\frac{11}5-16\int_0^1\frac x{x^3-4}dx\\
&=-\frac{11}5+\frac{8\sqrt[3]{2}}3\int_0^1\frac{x-\sqrt[3]{4}}{x^2+\sqrt[3]4x+2\sqrt[3]2}dx
-\frac{8\sqrt[3]2}3\int_0^1\frac{1}{x-\sqrt[3]{4}}dx\\
&=-\frac{11}5+
\frac{4\sqrt[3]{2}}3\int_0^1\frac{2x+\sqrt[3]{4}}{x^2+\sqrt[3]4x+2\sqrt[3]2}dx
-8\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt[3]4x+2\sqrt[3]2}dx
-\frac{8\sqrt[3]2}3\ln\left(1-\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{11}5+
\frac{4\sqrt[3]{2}}3\left(\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]2}\right)
-8\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2)^2+\frac32\sqrt[3]2}dx
-\frac{8\sqrt[3]2}3\ln\left(1-\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{2}\right)\\
\end{align}
Now
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2)^2+\frac32\sqrt[3]2}dx=\int_\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2^{1+\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2}\frac{1}{x^2+\frac32\sqrt[3]2}dx=\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{27}}\left(\arctan(\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{27}}(1+\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2))-\arctan(\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{27}}\frac{\sqrt[3]4}2)\right)
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with f(x)?

Comment: $\frac1{3m+5}=\int_0^1x^{3m+4}dx$. By "translating" the infinite series into an integral of a rational function, you can calculate it.

Comment: How did 3m + 5 become 3m + 4?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_quadrature_formula